# Bootstrap: overlapping columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .class1 {height: 100px; background-color: DarkSlateGrey}      
    </style>
    </head>  

    <body>
      <div class="container-fluid class1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">Website</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">Services</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">Services</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">Services</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">Services</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">Services</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">Services</div>    
        </div>
      </div>    
    </body>
   </html>
```

The problems with me are: 
When i do "inspect" to see the website on mobile:

-the background doesn't take all the width of mobile.

-Words "services" are overlapped, i want them to be separated with some spaces between them

How can I avoid these problems? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you see paddings of container-fluid but your background is centered? You can remove them by padding setting in class1. Regarding the word Services I believe that your font size is to big to fit into col-xs-1 containers and that results in overlaps. You should adjust font size for mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your width for each child inside the `row` is simply too small. For mobile size, you are setting the div to only 1/12 width of the mobile screen. You can add padding and `overflow: hidden` to it so it doesn't go over the desired width, but that doesn't seem ideal to me. I added a sample code based on your codes as an option for you to explore. If the screen is less than `>=720px` (`col-md`) then your first child in the row will take full width, and give more space for the rest so it looks more presentable.

```css
.class1 {
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: DarkSlateGrey
  }
.tomato{
  background: tomato;
}
.white{
  background: white;
}
row div{
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid class1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tomato col-xs-12 col-md-6">Website</div>
    <div class="white col-xs-4 col-md-1">Services</div>
    <div class="tomato col-xs-4 col-md-1">Services</div>
    <div class="white col-xs-4 col-md-1">Services</div>
    <div class="tomato col-xs-4 col-md-1">Services</div>
    <div class="white col-xs-4 col-md-1">Services</div>
    <div class="tomato col-xs-4 col-md-1">Services</div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer but i still have a question: is it possible to have "website" and all "services" on the same line on mobile without having overlapping?

Comment: @user10254054 yes using `position relative and absolute` then hide any `overflow` text or shorten the `website width`. However, none of it would be ideal or user-friendly.